# Error in Dynamic Edit distance

Tags: c, coredump, edit-distance

Goal of this program is to calculate for each word of file 'correctme.txt' the minimum edit distance inside 'dictionary.txt'.
I don't know why but my code goes to core dump (Segmentation Fault) after first for (inside). Function 'dynamic_edit_distance' is correct because i've already tested it.
Same as for 'read_quote' and 'read_dictionary'.
Why this error?

```
#define QUOTE_SIZE 100
#define DICTIONARY_SIZE 1000000

int main(){
  long i, j, min, a;
  char** quote = read_quote("correctme.txt", QUOTE_SIZE);
  char** dictionary = read_dictionary("dictionary.txt", DICTIONARY_SIZE);


  for(i = 0; i < QUOTE_SIZE; i++){
    min = QUOTE_SIZE;
    for(j = 0; j < DICTIONARY_SIZE; j++){
      dynamic_edit_distance(quote[i], dictionary[j]);
      min = a < min ? a : min;
    }
    printf("%s\tMinimum distance: %ld", quote[i], min);
  }

  //free memory

  for(i = 0; i < DICTIONARY_SIZE; i++)
    free(dictionary[i]);
  free(dictionary);
  for(i = 0; i < QUOTE_SIZE; i++)
    free(quote[i]);
  free(quote);
}
```

Comment: I don't see initialization of variable `a`.

Comment: try to comment the 3 functions and make a test using FIXED static const values and check if is all ok or not .

Comment: The problem is most likely in `read_quote`, in `read_dictionary` or in `dynamic_edit_distance`, which you didn't show.